# Compare two documents

Tags: algorithm, compare, document, string-comparison

There is a big dictionary, the vocabulary of which these documents are composed, with strictly one word from it in each document. I would like to compare these documents with each other, calculate a value, under which I would declare the two documents very different, and above which, very similar.

If a word is included in both documents, but in other documents rarely or not at all, it reinforces the similarity of the two documents, because it is a unique word that occurs only in these two.

If a word is included in both documents, but often also in other documents, this will weaken the similarity of the two documents, because it is a common word that will not make them similar.

Which method should I use? TF-IDF? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TF-IDF** is a good start for sure.

You could improve it though by also considering the text length of the document. This is what the library [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) does.

Lucene extended the TF-IDF formula by considering the length of the document, because this corresponds more to human intuition. After all, if you find the word "cat" in a document with one word, this term will be more relevant when compared to a single "cat" of a document with thousand words.

It seems that Lucene adopted an extended formula for TF-IDF:

```
log(numDocs / (docFreq + 1)) * sqrt(tf) * (1/sqrt(length))

numDocs = total number of documents
docFreq = in how many documents the word was found
tf      = Term frequency in a specific document
length  = How many words there are in the document
```

Nowadays it seems though that Lucene has evolved to use another algorithm called **BM25** ("Best Match 25"). Overall it seems that this algorithm produces better results than **TF-IDF**. It seems that the formula for BM25 used in Lucene is:

```
IDF * ((k + 1) * tf) / (k * (1.0 - b + b * (|d|/avgDl)) + tf)

k = constant (typically 1.2)
tf = term frequency
b = also a constant which tunes the influence of the document length
|d| = document length
avgDl = average document length
IDF = log ( numDocs / docFreq + 1) + 1
```

For more details on the Lucene implementation check this great [blog article](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/).